# Using nvl in a listagg SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, listagg, nvl

Having problems using an nvl call within a listagg.

I am new to SQL so I am still iffy on the syntax..

```
listagg(nvl(asgu.name, ', '),'In waiting')
   within group (order by asgu.name) as asgu_name,   
   case
   when asgu.name is not null then asgu.name
   else 'In Waiting'
   end 'In waiting',
```

Error: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

Comment: Add the full query along with sample data and expected result..

Comment: This is a really long query and I don't think you want to see the whole thing. Expected results are name and if field is null then I want it to say "In waiting". I can however tell you this query worked just fine before adding the nvl

Comment: Consider using [coalesce](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/coalesce.php) - better performance than `nvl`

Comment: @EdHeal I have tried this as well        coalesce(listagg(asgu.name, ', '), within group (order by asgu.name) as asgu_name, 'in waiting'),   and got ERROR:missing within

Comment: May I ask, what is your goal? It looks like you have your text reversed too. If you want the delimiter to be ', ' and the missing value to be 'In waiting', you would need to reverse them. But, that SQL should run as-is so I think the issues is somewhere else.

Comment: `listagg(nvl(asgu.name, 'In waiting'),', ')
   within group (order by asgu.name) as asgu_name`

Comment: You have no `from` keyword in your sample code, so it is really hard to make a suggestion.

Comment: @EdHeal - I agree with "Consider using `coalesce`" (for standard adherence reasons); however, how does it have better performance than `nvl`, when the second expression is a literal? I didn't get that. Thanks!

Comment: @mathguy - My mistake - it does not make any difference in this case. I think it is a good habit to get into IMHO

Answer (score 3):

Your `listagg()` code should probably look like this:

```
listagg(coalesce(asgu.name, 'In waiting'), ', ') within group (order by asgu.name) as asgu_names,
```

The other code doesn't make sense.  Either `asgu.name` is being aggregated or it is not being aggregated.  You should have an aggregation function for the second expression.

Answer (score 1):

The line `end 'In waiting'` is incorrect. You can use a space in a column alias, but it needs to be in double quotes (ie `end "In waiting"` )